# Are there any half-blood or muggle-born squibs?

Tags: harry-potter, squib

I remember other situations, like regular squibs and regular half-bloods, but I don't remember any mention of a half-blood squib or if it was even possible. I assume a muggle-born squib is impossible, but I just want confirmation.

Other questions do not discuss whether or not a squib can be born to one or no inherently-magical parents.

Comment: A muggle born squib is just a muggle isn't it?

Comment: @Don_Biglia No. Squibs can see magic and magical things.

Comment: Oh. Right ;) There might be, but there would no one to make them aware of it I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not sure that's known to be true.  Mrs. Figgs was obviously lying about seeing the Dementor, for example.  As far as I can see from the actual text, the only difference was that Squibs knew about the wizarding world, because they grew up in it.

Comment: Mrs. Figgs testified that she could feel the Dementors, though.

Comment: @JustinAlexander So could Dudley.

Comment: If there is a designation for someone who has a bit of magical talent, but not enough to train, it may be the equivalent of "Muggle-born squib".  Or a certain magical gift (like parsletongue, or Seeing, or empathy) but not wand magic.  That may or may not be the same thing as a squib brought up in the magical world, but who doesn't have magic - depends on whether it's a general term for those between, neither this nor that, or a specific term about those with the culture but not the ability.